# Save function is getting called multiple times in getContenttool when used with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rich-text-editor

I am trying to use a very good library named [contenttool](https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools) in angular so I have written one directive. On a page there any multiple editable fields, when I save any field my function gets called multiple times. Suppose I have 5 fields when I save any field then my save function gets called 5 times. This is the code which I have written.

```
app.directive('ngEditor',  function(){

    function link(scope, element, attrs){

        // Initialise the editor
        scope.editor = new ContentTools.EditorApp.get();
        scope.editor.init('[ng-editor]', 'ng-editor');

        // Bind a function on editor save
        if (scope.editor._bindings['saved'] && scope.editor._bindings['saved'].length > 0) {

        }
        scope.editor.addEventListener('saved', function (ev) {
            scope.$apply(function(){
                scope.regions = ev.regions;
                regions = ev.detail().regions;
                if (Object.keys(regions).length == 0) {
            return;
        }

            // Set the editor as busy while we save our changes
                scope.editor.busy(true);

        // Collect the contents of each region into a FormData instance
        payload = new FormData();
        for (name in regions) {
             if (regions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        payload.append(name, regions[name]);
              }
             }

        // Send the update content to the server to be saved
        function onStateChange(ev) {
            // Check if the request is finished
             if (ev.target.readyState == 4) {
                    scope.editor.busy(false);
                    if (ev.target.status == '200') {
                            // Save was successful, notify the user with a flash
                            new ContentTools.FlashUI('ok');
                        } else {
                            // Save failed, notify the user with a flash
                            new ContentTools.FlashUI('no');
                        }
                               }
                          }
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', onStateChange);
                xhr.open('POST', updateUrl);
                xhr.send(payload);
            });
        });
    }
    return {
        link: link
    }
})
```

Any solution to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an editor per field. From [the documentation](http://getcontenttools.com/api/content-tools#editor-app) you can see that

> The EditorApp class is actually a wrapper class that provides
>   singleton access to, by default, the out of the box content editor.

which means that if you link 5 times and you have one singleton for the editor you will actually register the events 5 times.

I am not completely sure how it looks like, but if I understand correctly it would be sufficient to register the `save` event only once. E.g. you might do this in the controller of your directive and make sure it is only called once.

Comment: This is the only code which I have written, Can you tell me what is wrong in this code ?

Comment: I guess what's wrong is that a 'save' event handler is registered in the link function. This link function is executed every-time you use an ng-editor in your html. Are you familiar with AngularJs?